# Linux: ps -awx vs. ps -awwx

Tags: linux, process, files, ps

Does anyone know the difference of `ps -awx vs. ps -awwx`?

I'm tracking down some processes, and I see significantly more information when I add an additional "w".  Does this work like in other cases (such as SSH debugging) when you issue multiple "v", the more "verbose" the output is?  I didn't see anything in the man pages about this.

Comment: [`man ps`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps): "-w Wide output. Use this option twice for unlimited width."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoth the man page (`man ps`):

```
 -w      Use 132 columns to display information, instead of the default which is your window
         size.  If the -w option is specified more than once, ps will use as many columns
         as necessary without regard for your window size.  
         When output is not to a terminal, an unlimited number of columns are always used.
```

---

Note that the above is from a BSD manpage.  A debian manpage is somewhat more terse/less specific, but similar:

```
        -w              Wide output. Use this option twice for unlimited width.
```

Comment: I must be reading a manpage that is "less" specific.  Sorry.

Comment: If your distribution's manpage doesn't even mention `-w` you should publicly name-and-shame them

Answer (score 4):

The `-w` switch says to use Wide output but the width is limited. Using `-ww` says to use unlimited width output so you get to see the full command line for a command wrapped as many times as it takes. Adding additional `w`s beyond 2 has no effect.